# 3D model print is fading out towards the sides

Tags: 3d-printing

I'm still new to Blender 3D and 3D printing in general, so don't judge me too hard if my issues is easily fixed :)

I've made curved model as you see below (left object), where I have a depth of 2.2 millmeters on the tree and sun image, but as you might see in the actual print, it looks like it is fading out towards the edges and still nowhere near 2 millimeters in the middle. The text should be 1.5 millimeters

The right object is similar, but flat and with not surrounding text, and that is printed without any details as you also can see below.

The tree and sun object is a copy of each other, same modifiers, except the Curve modifier on the left object.

Is there a logic explanation to why one is printed without the details and one is printing some of it, but fading out?
Not sure if it is needed, but we are using Chitubox to slice and print in resin.

Thank you in advance

Blender-file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApWO17TJv3pvhKN7rFcAgFxPUKgfvg?e=hF3RTU

Stl-file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApWO17TJv3pvhKN8VlG8jM-BlsZ-fA?e=QbQhvm

[image: This shows the difference between model and actual print]

Comment: How did you cut out the text for the model on the left? There's no *Boolean* modifier on it. I don't do 3D printing but the mesh topology of both models doesn't seem right to me. They are non-manifold (=there are holes in it), the right one has duplicated vertices and there are intersecting faces. You also use the *Edge Split* modifier to keep the edges sharp. It would be better to add two so-called "support loops"/"holding loops". Blender comes with the add-on "Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox". Enabled it in the Preferences then you can check the mesh with it. Have you considered to remesh the models?

Comment: @Blunder, the text is "cut out" by recalculating Normals and turn it "inside out", kind of a negative object and thereby not printing that space.
Let me check the duplicated vertices (if I can figure it out) and same goes for remeshing the models :)

Do you know what Zero faces and Zero edges means?

Comment: Ah okay. I didn't knew that it can be printed this way without a boolean operation. To remove duplicated vertices, go in *Edit* mode, select everything (key A), and do a *Merge By Distance* (key M). I guess this will remove the Zero Faces and Zero Edges, too. These are faces that have no area and edges that have 0 length. For the remesh try the *Remesh* modifier. The minimal voxel size is 0.1 mm which still results in a "blocky" appearance since your model is so tiny. You can scale it up by 10, apply the scale (Object mode, Ctrl+A), remesh it, and scale it down again + apply scale.